# implement the | operator within a compare

Tags: c#

Im working on some input handling and i wanted to implement a shorthand for this

```
if (KeyboardEvents.Down.Contains(Keys.LeftShift) || KeyboardEvents.Down.Contains(Keys.RightShift))
```

into this

```
if (KeyboardEvents.Down.Contains(Keys.LeftShift | Keys.RightShift))
```

I have seen this kind of syntax a few times used within attributes like this.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct)]
```

I'm not sure if its at all possible to do the way I want to, but it would be a fancy shorthand simplifying several if's.

Yes the shorthand compiles, so obviously it does something, but not what I thought it would (so another question to the problem is, what does it actually do?).

here is the structure behind the keyboard input handling.

```
public static class KeyboardEvents
{
    public static KeyboardState State { get { return Keyboard.GetState(); } }
    public static Keys[] Down = new Keys[0];
    public static IEnumerable<Keys> WasDown = new Keys[0];
    public static void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Keys[] NewDown = State.GetPressedKeys();
        WasDown = Down.Except(NewDown);
        Down = NewDown;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `KeyboardEvents`?

Comment: That makes no sense because the first one is a logical or `||` but the second one is a bitwise or `|`. Those two are doing different things ;-)

Comment: ohh i see the problem now. the reason it compiles but don't hits is because  I'm actually ORing the RightShift and leftShift onto each other into a new value which I'm sending back. well that's embarrassing, I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bitwise OR and logical OR have different meanings. The former will do a bitwise or between two flags, meaning:

```
Class = 0x0004,
Struct = 0x0008,
```

Will make the enum value of `AttributeTarget` equal to `0x0012` which is bitwise OR between the two values.

You can see this yourself with a simple example:

```
var targetAttributes = AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct;
Console.WriteLine((int)targetAttributes);
```

The logical OR means "Evaluate the left hand expression, if it evaluates to true, follow through the branch. Otherwise, evaluate the right hand expression, if it evaluates to true, follow the branch".

If `KeyboardEvents` is an `enum`, you can use [`Enum.HasFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if any of the flags are set:

```
if (KeyboardEvents.HasFlag(Keys.LeftShift | Keys.RightShift))
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: the KeyboardEvents is a static class and the Down is a array of enums

Comment: Why do you need a `List<Enum>`?

Comment: It's used to know what was down, its more of a temporary list between updates. really should be using a.Except(b) for the readablility

Answer (score 2):

You can turn it around and say

```
if({Keys.LeftShift, Keys.RightShift}.contains(KeyboardEvents.Down)).
```